# Can't set variable value to script in Postman

Tags: postman

There are two tests in the request, I want to use a different value of the variable in the second request, I set it using the command

```
pm.variables.set("confirm_emal", "vodani6277@ulforex.com");
```

Can't set variable value separately for second script

```
pm.test("Confirmed email", () =>{
//parse the response JSON and test three properties
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(responseJson.email).to.eql('gekisa9678@exoacre.com');
pm.expect(responseJson.auth_key).to.be.eql('557UmPdC2pGV_tA67bSjHGPbtbRz90Hk');
pm.expect(responseJson.first_name).to.eql('Vitalijj');
pm.expect(responseJson.last_name).to.eql('Agarev');
pm.expect(responseJson.birthday_date).to.eql(978307200);
pm.expect(responseJson.register_type).to.eql('email');
pm.expect(responseJson.email_confirmed).to.eql("true");
```

});

```
pm.test("unconfirmed email", () =>{

    pm.variables.set("confirm_emal", "vodani6277@ulforex.com");
  
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(responseJson.email).to.eql('vodani6277@ulforex.com');
    pm.expect(responseJson.register_type).to.eql('email');
    pm.expect(responseJson.email_confirmed).to.eql(false);
});
```

I get an error that the expected value does not match the response from the server
AssertionError: expected 'vodani6277@ulforex.com' to deeply equal 'gekisa9678@exoacre.com'

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure I understand where that variable is getting used  Also, `pm. variables.set()` is only used in the context of that request so if you're trying to use that in a different request, it's not going to work. You're going to need to save that in a different variable scope.

Comment: it's the same request, just in the second script, I wanted to change the value of the variable.

Comment: That wouldn't be a change that could be used outside of that request context, it doesn't store that value after that full request has been executed. You would need to use `pm.environment/globals/collectionVariables` to do that as `pm.variables` in only a temp change.

Comment: I realized my mistake, all tests are evaluated after the request is executed. I just wrote a test with sending a request using the sendRequest method